# How did the unpublishing of npm left-pad break code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been reading up on the npm left-pad fiasco, but I'm somewhat confused by how it happened. I think I have a misunderstanding of how npm actually works. If the developer of left-pad unpublished the package, I assume `npm install left-pad` wouldn't work anymore. However, for users who had already installed it, won't left-pad still be in the node_modules folder? Wouldn't the developers of say, Babel, have to remove and reinstall left-pad for npm to realize that the package has disappeared? I am clearly missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding NPM, you're misinterpreting the clickbait titles that were around at the time. It means it would break if anyone tried `npm install`ing from `package.json` referncing the `left-pad`, not literally run-time. I've even seen a title along the lines of "How one man almost broke the internet". Sigh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I run `npm install babel`, left-pad is not bundled in babel but rather is expressed as dependency in it's package.json file. So npm then has to go find left-pad and download it as well. So if you were installing left-pad or anything using left-pad for the first time, you wouldn't be able to. While this means you're safe if it already exists in your local directory, the project would fail to build properly as soon as it is built somewhere else. For example, a CI server that does a clean build from scratch for each new changeset would fail to build any project that relies on left-pad. Or if you were checking out a project for the first time, or deploying it to a new server, you wouldn't be able to build.

This is simple to fix if you were relying on left-pad directly. Just write a replacement and update your code to use the replacement. But when it's required deep in your dependency tree, say by Babel, it's unlikely you can refactor Babel or other modules on your own to use a left-pad replacement. You'd have to wait for all of the various node module developers to update their modules with something else and republish.

It's not as apocalyptic as news articles made it sounds, but it is a huge inconvenience and throws a wrench in many systems outside of developer workspaces where left-pad was already cached.

Comment: Ninja'd. You forgot to talk about dependency of dependency, if I remember the event, it was the main problem. Good explication though :)

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense (: Would it really be hard to refactor dependencies though? Since you already have a copy from before, is it not possible to make that local module part of the whole project just by committing that one module in?

Comment: @TimothyDeng How do you get the dependencies to point to your local copy? I think you'd have to fork each one and change their require statements to point to your copy. Then you'd have to republish each one. Probably possible but not efficient or sustainable.

Comment: Is it necessary to republish? Wouldn't it be trivial to integrate that piece of code into the project by simply copying the module into a different directory and changing the require to the absolute path? This should require it as a standard JavaScript file, right? You wouldn't have to publish to npm, but for modules that likely don't need updating (like left-pad), why not integrate them directly into the project?

Comment: @TimothyDeng It's certainly possible to move modules from the node_modules dir and into your project and modify them, but it's not advisable or sustainable as I mentioned. It's not realistic to expect all developers everywhere to suddenly take ownership of all their dependencies because one went missing. Better to heal the ecosystem (publish a replacement left-pad, all module owners push new versions), than to make everyone fend for themselves.

Comment: I see, thanks! That does seem to be a better solution overall.

Answer (score 2):

As @Lazar said, you understood correctly.

The problem come in that, if Babel is relying on left-pad, and am trying to install Babel, it will fail.

Well, I could always rewrite it myself as a workaround.

But if it is a module used by a module used by a module used by... used by Babel, or more module, you face a real nightmare, because Babel can't do anything, nor can you, and you are forced to wait that every single module develloper relying on left-pad update their code.

Comment: It is worth noting that tools like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire), [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), [JSPM](https://github.com/jspm/jspm), etc. actually provide for arbitrary dependency subgraphs to be controlled, aliased, and swapped out. So a large part of the technical problem is _relying_ on NPM to manage dependencies because of how _it_ in turn effectively delegates to the Node.js `require` algorithm (i.e. it just writes files to disk for it to find). So it was still possible to use the transitively dependent version of Babel during this time frame.